# Pre-commit hook. Svnlook can't find the path ".tmp\format"

Tags: batch-file, svn, pre-commit-hook, svn-repository, svnlook

I've made **pre-commit.bat** script, but it doesn't work properly.
I want it to prevent sending commits without proper message("Ticket xxxxx").

Here's the code:

```
set REPOS=%1  
set TXN=%2  
svnlook log %REPOS% -t %TXN% | findstr /r "^Ticket [0-9]{5}" > nul || echo   "Follow the format [Ticket xxxxx ...]" 1>&2 && exit 1  
exit 0
```

And here's what I get when I try to commit:

```
The hook script returned an error:  
svnlook: E720003: Can't open file 'C:\Users\EDUARD~5.LI\AppData\Local\Temp\3\svn4FA6.tmp\format': The system cannot find the path specified.    
"Follow the format [Ticket xxxxx ...]"
```

**Settings for the hook are:**
Working copy path - D:\test\testwc
Command line to execute - D:\test\hooks\pre-commit.bat

**Subversion client** - TortoiseSVN

I'm trying to commit changes of the "D:\test\testwc\test.txt" file.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess you are setting up a client-side hook script, but the `svnlook` tool is designed for server-side usage; I think `svn log` is the suitable client-side tool; or -- even better -- use the parameter `%3` (like `set "MESSAGEFILE=%~3"`), and then use `type "%MESSAGEFILE%" | > nul findstr /R "^Ticket [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" || (>&2 echo Follow the format [Ticket xxxxx ...]) & exit /B 1` (see the quotes around the path, the corrected regular expression and the changed operator `&` instead of `&&`)...

Comment: Did you get a satisfactory answer, Eduard?

Comment: No, unfortunately. @DavidWhite